# Default phantom caption in VB6 textbox

Tags: vb6

How can I do this in VB6.0...

> > > There's a default Caption in Textbox when it is empty, let say "Enter Name Here". but when the user fills in, the Caption will be replaced...

Comment: He means a cuetip or placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Text1_Change()  
If Trim(Text1.Text) = "" Then
Label1.Caption = "Enter Name Here"
Else
Label1.Caption = ""
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_Click()
Label1.Caption = "Enter Name Here"
End Sub

Private Sub Text1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
If Trim(Text1.Text) = "" Then
 Label1.Caption = "Enter Name Here"
Else
 Label1.Caption = ""
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Sourav: Please don't beg for votes in the comments. It's been 3 minutes; no one can accept your answer that quickly anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I looked at your recent questions, but none of them concern anything I know anything about. Otherwise, I'd be happy to help. I'm not sure what that has to do with begging for upvotes, though...

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was accepted. It shows the caption on a **label** control, rather than in the textbox itself. The other solutions all seem much more appropriate and in-line with what the asker was seeking. If you're going to use a separate label control to display the prompt text, it's not clear why you can't just display the label text *all the time*. The only reason you'd need to hide it would be if it was actually displayed in the textbox, and needed to get out of the way when the user started typing.

Comment: a textbox can not have a CAPTION in VB 6.0, but  a label have !

Comment: Yes it can. The property is called `Text`, every `TextBox` control has it. It gets/sets what is displayed in the text box itself. You've not provided an answer to the question that was asked (*"There's a default Caption in Textbox when it is empty, let say "Enter Name Here". but when the user fills in, the Caption will be replaced..."*). It boggles the mind how this was acceptable to the asker.

Answer (score 8):

The Windows API has had [cue banners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761639.aspx) (or prompt text) built in since Windows XP. It's not directly exposed by VB 6, but that doesn't stop you from getting at it by making a few API calls.

There are several advantages of going this route, versus implementing your own custom style. For one thing, it's already available for free, meaning you have to do very little work to use it. Second, it's already been fully tested and professionally polished. Third, it will automatically get upgrades whenever the next version of Windows comes out.

All the code you need is available here: **[SendMessage: Use Cue Banners to Prompt Users](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/textapi/setcuebanner.htm)**

As the page explains, you need to make sure that you've included a manifest with your EXE so that you can take advantage of the Windows XP themes and features. The only real tricky part about the code is that you need to make sure you pass a *Unicode* string.

The final effect looks something like this:

[image: Cue Banner sample]

Answer (score 2):

if you want a default value in the textbox until a user selects the box to begin typing:

use the GotFocus() event for your textbox and insert the following as your code:  `txtName.text = ""`

in the LostFocus() event use:

```
If txtName.text = "" Then
txtName.text = "Enter Name Here"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Native win32 Alternative:

```
Private Const ECM_FIRST As Long = &H1500
Private Const EM_SETCUEBANNER As Long = (ECM_FIRST + 1)

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function InitCommonControls Lib "comctl32" () As Long

Private Sub Form_Initialize()
    InitCommonControls
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim sCueCaption As String
    sCueCaption = StrConv("Enter Name Here", vbUnicode)
    Call SendMessage(Text1.hwnd, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0&, ByVal sCueCaption)
End Sub
```

This needs a manifest so the following saved as "`<exename>.exe.manifest`" (Can also use a resource)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly
   xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
   manifestVersion="1.0">
   <assemblyIdentity
      type="win32"
      processorArchitecture="*"
      version="6.0.0.0"
      name="test"
   />
   <description>Enter your Description Here</description>
   <dependency>
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            language="*"
            processorArchitecture="*"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
         />
      </dependentAssembly>
   </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Form_Initialize is often too late for calling InitCommonControls, do it in Sub Main instead.  Also you will find that even this crashes sometimes unless you load Shell32.dll before calling InitCommonControls.  To avoid "works on MY machine" syndrome do both of these in the right sequence before loading any Forms.  A call to IsUserAnAdmin in Shell32 is enough to get it loaded, you don't need LoadLibrary.

Comment: Why call `InitCommonControls` at all? The function is deprecated and has been replaced by **`InitCommonControlsEx`**. The latter is available at least as far back as Windows 2000, and provides much more flexibility in the control classes that you register. The former *only* registers the Windows 95 classes. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775695.aspx) for details.

Comment: @Bob: LoadLibrary prevents a crash on application shutdown if VB runtime unloads shell32 too early. It works by locking the dll in process space until process is terminated completely.

Comment: @wqw: I've never heard of such a thing. What could possibly cause the VB runtime to unload `shell32.dll` too early? The only time this *might* apply is if you're subclassing. That's not the case here, there's no chance of the DLL being unloaded too early. (And there are better ways to subclass. `LoadLibrary` isn't the answer.)